# Want to duplicate work environment

Tags: system-installation

At work they are running virtual linux servers. I do some scripting for them .. basically I want to duplicate the work environment so that I can script against my network lab at the house. Ive been using some flavor of Unix for quite some time and have held a job where one of my responsibilities was first level .. kind of a mini admin roll but Ive never done actual admin work.

So my question is, will Ubuntu server run inside Oracle VM. I have plenty of RAM and disk space.. 24gig of ram and a 500g hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Ubuntu, or most any version of Linux will run on most any virtualization as a guest.